# Can't converting XElement to decimal

Tags: c#, linq, decimal, xelement

I'm trying to read a XElement and convert it to a decimal.
Sumkwh is decimal and the input is:

```
<detaillinie>
        <periode>2016-04-27 06:30:00</periode>
        <kWh>0,35225</kWh>
      </detaillinie>
      <detaillinie>
        <periode>2016-04-27 06:45:00</periode>
        <kWh>0,35225</kWh>
      </detaillinie>
      <detaillinie>
        <periode>2016-04-27 07:00:00</periode>
        <kWh>0,17875</kWh>
</detaillinie>
```

The code looks like this:

```
 var query =
                from timeserie in xdoc.Descendants("detaillinie").AsEnumerable()
                select new TimeSerie
                {
                    Sumdato = (DateTime)timeserie.Element("periode"), 
                    Sumkwh = (decimal)timeserie.Element("kWh")

                }
```

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Inputstring was in a wrong format.

If I manually type 
`Sumkwh = decimal.parse("0,2435")` I get no error.

I have tryed with 
`Sumkwh = decimal.parse(timeserie.Element("kWh"))` 
it gives the error "Cannot convert from 'system.xml.linq.xelement' to string.

Any help please :)

Comment: Your code is not complete.

Comment: Try `Sumkwh = decimal.Parse(timeserie.Element("kWh").ToString())`

Comment: Your input is using `,` as decimal separator, while XML is supposed to write/read invariant culture formatted values.

Comment: Seriously, learn how to use the Visual Studio Debugger. No offense intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeserie.Element("kWh")` is a `XElement`, you need to grab it's `Value`.

Use

```
decimal.Parse(timeserie.Element("kWh").Value)
```

Comment: Hmm, can see now that it was the .value that did the trick not the culture. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

As per your answer your parsing code of your `query` and your `manual` parsing line are different.

in your manual line you are parsing with decimal.Parse();

so, why are you not parsing same as in your query.

try

```
Sumkwh = decimal.parse(timeserie.Element("kWh").Value);
```

in your query and dont forget to get value from your element.

Comment: My mistake. This works. I just did'nt have the .value . thank you

Answer (score 1):

While `XElement` (and `XAttribute`) have explicit operators defined for converting their values, they do so by using the invariant culture.

This works for your timestamp, but the decimal is not formatted correctly and uses a comma as decimal seperator.

If possible I would suggest serializing the values to the XML document using invariant culture too. If this is not possible you have to explicitely parse the value using the appropriate culture, i.e.

```
Decimal.Parse(timeserie.Element("kWh").Value, new CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the culture that were missing. But why could I pass the string "1,234" ??

Comment: @TBoy3 The invariant culture uses the `,` as number group seperator. The parsed number is `1234`. Which makes is really dangerous parsing decimals from unknown sources.